# The camp leader would like to line the children up so that there are at most $2014$ children between any pair of friends.

Tags: combinatorics

There are $2014^{2014}$ children at a mathematics camp. Each has at most three friends at the camp, and if A is friends with B, then B is friends with A. The camp leader would like to line the children up so that there are at most $2014$ children between any pair of friends. Is it always possible to do this?

I thought maybe the pigeon hole principle. Obviously the 2014 is arbitrary. I googled it looking for a solution and it turns out it is from the BMO round 2. there it is 2010.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: what if there were no friends?

Comment: I don't think that counts.

Comment: No friends vacuously satisfies the conclusion. In fact you can assume that each child has at least one friend - otherwise you can put all the friendless children (aw) at one end of the line.

Comment: If there are no loners, then would the worst outcome be that they all have $1$ friend each?

Comment: Is that meant to be *a least 2014 children*?

Comment: No, its not. The key words are "always possible"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number of children is (totally unrealistic since larger than the number of atoms in the galaxy, but) essentially unlimited for the purpose of the argument below (I'll check at the end). We can choose our friendships as we go.

Pick a child. Give it three friends form the unlimited supply of remaining children. Then give each of them two more friends from the remainder, then all new ones two more friends, and continue like that. After $n$ iterations, we've encountered $3\times2^n-2$ children. But all of them must be at no more than $2015n$ distance from the original child in the line-up. This becomes impossible when $4030n<3\times2^n-2$, which is fairly soon, in fact for $n=15$ it is already the case.

I've only "used" some $100\,000$ children in the argument, way less than the available number.